# jsf2.0 commandLink inside ui:repeat is not working

Tags: jsf-2

I m having problem with commandLink, it is working in my table at the first  but other  are made inside ui:repeate and the commandLink there is not working

```
<tr>
                            <td rowspan="#{form25Bean.forms1size}">Наименования научных
                                лабораторий:</td>

                            <td>#{form25Bean.forms1first.sciencenName}</td>
                            <td>#{form25Bean.forms1first.innovationName}</td>
                            <td>#{form25Bean.forms1first.ppcPortion}</td>
                            <td><h:commandLink value="удалить" id="cl2"
                                    action="#{form25Bean.remove}">
                                    <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                        target="#{form25Bean.selectedForm}" value="#{form25Bean.forms1first}" />
                                </h:commandLink> <h:column>
                                    <h:commandLink value="изменить" action="#{form25Bean.edit}">
                                        <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                            target="#{form25Bean.selectedForm}" value="#{form}" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </h:column></td>
                        </tr>
                        <ui:repeat var="f1" value="#{form25Bean.forms1}">
                        <h:form>
                            <tr>
                                <td>#{f1.sciencenName}</td>
                                <td>#{f1.innovationName}</td>
                                <td>#{f1.ppcPortion}</td>
                                <td><h:commandLink value="удалить" id="cl2"
                                        action="#{form25Bean.remove}">
                                        <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                            target="#{form25Bean.selectedForm}" value="#{f1}" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                     <h:column>
                                         <h:commandLink value="изменить" action="#{form25Bean.edit}">
                                            <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                                target="#{form25Bean.selectedForm}" value="#{f1}" />
                                         </h:commandLink>
                                    </h:column></td>
                            </tr>
                            </h:form>
                        </ui:repeat>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you got nested forms

There is a form wrapping your entire table (cause you got several `h:commandLink` above the `<ui:repeat` )

And there is a `form` inside the `ui:repeat`

Take a look at your generated source code (html) , you got `<form>.... <form>....</form></form>`

get rid of the nested forms... (for example remove the `<h:form>` from `ui:repeat`)